# How to store array in file(database) and how to access it in program

Tags: c, arrays, database, file, arraylist

In C, how to store array in file(database) and how to access it in program. In this program when I enter index number for ex.2 (which contains 30), after I want to subtract the age by 5 then it shows 25 but when I want to change the index number 2 then it subtracted from 25,,,not from the given index

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define PATH "/storage/emulated/0/c language/data2.txt"

int main()
{
    FILE *file;
    int age[] = {15,10,19,3}, s,i;
    printf("Enter the array index:");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    file = fopen(PATH, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("files does not exist");
        return 1;
    }
    fscanf(file, "%d", &age[i]);
    fclose(file);
    printf("Enter how much age should to be subtracted:");
    scanf("%d", &s);

    file = fopen(PATH, "w");
    age[i] = age[i] - s;
    fprintf(file, "%d", age[i]);
    fclose(file);
    printf("%d", age[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to store the data from the file in an array, edit it and then load it back in the file.

```
fscanf(file, "%d", &age[i]);
```

This code reads the first integer in the file and loads it in age[i]

```
fprintf(file, "%d", age[i]);
```

Replaces contents of the file with age[i] and after that you will get a file only with 1 number.